# Multiple components to result in one value with Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have 3 `<select>` components. In the first component I have the days, in the second the months and in the third the years. These components act as one date picker. I tried to wrap with Formik's `connect` and use `setFieldValue` and `setFieldError`, but the error disappears after I edit an other component in that form.

How can I solve it to the error remain persistent. As I saw, this behaviour is [known](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1309).

```
class DateField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const value = props.value;
    this.state = {
      day: moment.utc(value).date(),
      month: moment.utc(value).month(),
      year: moment.utc(value).year(),
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const stateProp = e.target.name.split('.').pop();

    this.setState(
      {
        [stateProp]: e.target.value,
      },
      () => {
        const { formik } = this.props;
        const date = this.dateFromState();
        const error = this.props.validate(date);
        formik.setFieldValue(this.props.name, date, false);
        formik.setFieldError(this.props.name, error);
      }
    );
  };

  handleBlur = () => {
    const { formik } = this.props;
    const date = this.dateFromState();
    const error = this.props.validate(date);
    formik.setFieldTouched(this.props.name, true, false);
    formik.setFieldError(this.props.name, error);
  };

  dateFromState() {
    // returns date constructed from the state
  }

  render() {
    const { formik, name } = this.props;
    const error = getValueByPath(formik.errors, name);

    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>{this.props.label}</label>
        <select
          name={`${this.props.name}.day`}
          value={this.state.day}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        >
          {
            // options for days
          }
        </select>
        <select
          name={`${this.props.name}.month`}
          value={this.state.month}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        >
          {
            // options for months
          }
        </select>
        <select
          name={`${this.props.name}.year`}
          value={this.state.year}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        >
          {
            // options for years
          }
        </select>
        {error && (
          <div className="validation-message">
            <span>{error}</span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const getValueByPath = (obj, path) => path.split('.').reduce((o, i) => o && o[i], obj);

export default connect(DateField);
```

Comment: Where does the function getValueByPath come from?

Comment: I updated the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be in de-coupling the component from formik, let it provide a date and handle change accordingly. the form in which you use this can then determine if the provided date is valid or not and pass the error to your controlled component to show until the date is valid. This is also great for re-usability.

```
const DatePicker = ({ name, value, error, onChange, onBlur }) => {
  const today = new Date(value);  
  const [day, setDay] = useState(today.getUTCDay());
  const [month, setMonth] = useState(today.getUTCMonth());
  const [year, setYear] = useState(today.getUTCYear());

  useEffect() => {
   const newDate = new Date([year, month, day]);
   const target = { name, value: newDate };

   onChange({ target });
  }, [day, month, year]);

  return (
    //do your JSX here;
  );
}
```

Comment: Managed to resolve it, but started from your idea. I used a hidden field to connect with formik. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)